# All day event from .ics file not importing properly into Google Calendar

Tags: ruby, icalendar

I'm generating .ics files using the icalendar rubygem. I'm having issues with "All Day" events with import into Google Calendar. Importing into iCal works perfectly fine. Events with specific date/time work perfectly in both calendars.

**UPDATE:**

The issue actually happens when tapping the "Add to calendar" in the Android Gmail app. The import of the all-day event is actually correct if I tap the actual .ics file attachment at the bottom of the email.

**.ics file (Validated by online validator):**

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:icalendar-ruby
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20200602T175210Z
UID:d033afdd-2eaa-4adf-aed7-63d1732a4322
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20201102
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20201103
CLASS:PRIVATE
DESCRIPTION:General - All Day
LOCATION:Some Address
SUMMARY:Test Event
URL:http://localhost:5000/events/129/signup
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

**eMail in Gmail Android app screenshot:**

[image]

**Google Calendar app screenshot after taping on "Add to calendar" in Gmail on Android:**

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/icalendar/icalendar/issues/71 look at the last comment, might help

Comment: I figured out that taping the .ics file works perfectly fine in Gmail Android app. However, tapping the "Add to calendar" link at the top of the eMail does not.